# How can I reference a RegEx capture group in TeXstudio's find & replace?

Tags: texstudio

In TeXstudio, I am trying to use the RegEx find & replace functionality to edit image file paths used in my document. For every file name, I am trying to add `img/` to the beginning of the path. I have come up with the following RegEx:

```
(includegraphics[^{]*{)([^{]+\.png)
```

As you can see, I have two capture groups. How can I reference those in the replace box? I tried `$1` and `%1`, but both don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\1` (or `\2` etc.) to insert capture groups in TeXstudio. In this case, that would mean:

```
\1img/\2
```